# known list of gestures or library of gestures we can use in our android projects

Tags: android

I have come up with some terms used for specific gestures - pinch-zoom, two-finger glide etc. is there a known list of gestures or library of gestures to use in android projects?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. https://github.com/stevenkaras/Android-TouchLib
2. [How to use Multi-touch in Android](http://www.zdnet.com/blog/burnette/how-to-use-multi-touch-in-android-2/1747)
3. http://developer.android.com/training/gestures/detector.html
4. http://developer.android.com/reference/android/gesture/GestureStore.html

For tutorial on GestureBuilder and incorporating it in your project, see http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidGestures/article.html

Comment: thanks for the links, it helps. But still looking for a list of terms used for various gestures.

Comment: I think you're going about it wrong looking for "terms" used for various gestures. You should create your own gestures using the developer.android training link. In your Android SDK manager, under example projects, there is tool called "Gesture Builder", simply  install that onto your phone, and create new gestures and add them to your project using the developer.android link. It's the easiest way to work with gestures.

Comment: that is interesting, can you explain a bit how to add them to the project using developer.android link please...

Comment: Sure. I was able to use this tutorial to incorporate Gestures into my project. See this link and follow it, it explains it in detail step by step: http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidGestures/article.html